# Why the redux state is undefined after my action call inside componentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a problem annoying me for a while so here it is... I'm trying to fetch details from an API of mine, so I created an async action creator and as it is usually done I invoke it inside the `componentDidmount()`. the problem is I want to access the props immediately after the action call but whenever I run `console.log(this.props.note)` it prints undefined. so how can I access the redux state after the call?

**My action:**

```
export const fetchNoteDetail = (id, ) => async dispatch => {
    const response = await notes.get(`notes/${id}`)

    dispatch({type: 'FETCH_NOTE_DETAIL', payload: response.data})
}
```

**ComponentDidMount():**

```
   componentDidMount() {
      const {id} = this.props.match.params
      this.props.fetchNoteDetail(id)

      console.log(this.props.note) //undefined

    }
```

Comment: `fetchNoteDetail` is asynchronous, so it actually runs after the `console.log` statement does. (But even if it were synchronous, it would only update the Redux store synchronously - your React component will only receive its new props and rerender a short time later, again after the `componentDidMount` has finished.)

Comment: Firstly if the fetched data is stored in redux store that is not how you access redux store in class component that which I am assuming you are using based on you mentioning **compoentDidMount** etc

Comment: Secondly please add code of your redux store plus reducer

Comment: @RobinZigmond so by any chance aren't there any possible ways that I could make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

run this `console.log` inside `componentDidUpdate()`